# How to convert to_timestamp from oracle to mysql timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-conversion

This if from

```
oracle to_timestamp('17-SEP-20 12.32.25.644000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')
```

Need something like this for sql

```
STR_TO_DATE('17-SEP-20 12.32.25.644000000 PM','%d-%b-%Y %H.%i.%s.%f %p')
```

Comment: i am not able to handle that many millisecond. But this one is working. `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('17-SEP-20 12.32.25.644 AM', '%d-%M-%Y %h.%i.%s.%f %p')),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i:%p')`

Comment: As a rule of thumb I avoid using the `TIMESTAMP` data type in MySQL. It can be error prone since it heavily depends on the server configuration and not your appliction logic. Also it'll become obsolete in 18 years from now (in 2038). Use `DATETIME` instead.